# CSS Flex row direction with 50% column stretch

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to learn how CSS flex works. I want to create a full-width and full-height panel with some blocks (items). I don't understand how do I create 2 vertical items with 50% height each when flex-direction is row (pink and yellow blocks on images).

Here is my goal:

[image: flex layout goal]

Here is what I got for now:

[image: flex layout I make]

And here is my code:

```css
 body {
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .container .item
    {    
       margin: 10px;
    }

    .item.blue {
      flex: 0 1 80%;
      background: blue;
    }

    .item.green {
      flex: 0 1 auto;
      background: green;
    }

    .item.red {
        flex: 0 1 60%;
        background: red;
    }

    .item.pink {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
      background: pink;
      align-self: stretch;
    }

    .item.orange{
      flex: 0 1 60%;
      background: orange;
    }

    .item.yellow {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
      align-self: center;
      background: yellow;
    }

    .item.purple{
      flex: 1 0 auto;
      background: purple;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item blue">
        blue
    </div>
    <div class="item green">
        green
    </div>
    <div class="item red">
        red
    </div>
    <div class="item pink">
        pink
    </div>
    <div class="item orange">
        orange
    </div>
    <div class="item yellow">
        yellow
    </div>
    <div class="item purple">
        purple
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You may have better luck with CSS Grid here, but it is pretty simple if you add more wrappers in there around the stacked items.

Comment: I started using grid, with I read that flex performance is better than grid. Is that correct?

Comment: True, but it is a lot more powerful. If you have a bunch of elements that you need to configure in complex ways in multiple breakpoints, grid can be a good choice.

Comment: The only problem of grid is that it isn't supported by all browsers (Internet Explorer), but the browser will die soon. So i would recommend you grid for 2d structures and flex for 1d structures(f.e. header-navigation, or footer-navigation)

Comment: internet explorer requires prefix and also assign a position into the grid for each element. (grid-row/grid-column) but indeed, for auto-flow, grid and IE do not work. This layout looks like a typical grid layout because you have elements spanning through rows (or columns) which is something that flex does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do all of this with a long, wrapping, flex row, you could add additional rows and column wrappers and still use flex benefits. This way you aren't using occasional self-align properties or things that may be hard to maintain, and the html more semantically resembles the layout.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
  min-height: 100px;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex: 0 1 60%;
}

.column:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.item {
  min-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item.blue {
  flex: 0 1 80%;
  background: blue;
}

.item.green {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: green;
}

.item.red {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  background: red;
}

.item.orange {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: orange;
}

.item.pink {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

.item.yellow {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.item.purple {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item blue">
    blue
  </div>
  <div class="item green">
    green
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item red">
      red
    </div>
    <div class="item orange">
      pink
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item pink">
      orange
    </div>
    <div class="item yellow">
      yellow
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item purple">
    purple
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try to create a grid, by creating row class and col class, It will be easy to place these div's.
something like these

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

and arrange you div's